# Как сделать определенный выбор по полям моделей в rest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Я новичок в rest, пытаюсь воссоздать работу приложения для записи в салон красоты.
У меня есть допустим 2 салона для записи клиента. В каждом салоне работают разные мастера. Так вот моя проблема в том что при попытке записи в один из салонов, я могу выбрать любого мастера и это работает...Я же хочу сделать так чтобы при выборе 1 салона можно было выбрать только мастера который работает в этом салоне. Гуглил искал, но если честно даже не представляю на какую тему почитать, как правильно назвать ситуацию. Где то попадалась информация что при выборе поля, запрос не отправляется, тоесть без javascript не обойтись, я прав ? Или это можно как-то реализовать ? Спасибо за любую помощь.

Я пытался отфильтровать через get_queryset. Но это не то что мне нужно, он просто выводит отфильтрованную информацию уже в выводе на странице.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from salon.resources import SERVICES


class Salon(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Название салона')
    info = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='О салоне')
    time = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text='БЕЗ ВЫХОДНЫХ с 10:00 до 22:00',
                            verbose_name='Часы работы')
    address = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Адрес')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, help_text='Формат ввода: +70123456789', verbose_name='Телефон')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name='Электронная почта')
    web = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Сайт')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Салон'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Салоны'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class Services(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Название услуги')
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание услуги')
    services = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=SERVICES, default='nails', verbose_name='Выбор услуги')
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0, null=True, verbose_name='Стоимость услуги')
    salon = models.ManyToManyField(Salon, verbose_name='Выбор салона')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Услуга'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Услуги'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class Master(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='Имя мастера')
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, verbose_name='Фотография мастера')
    info = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание работ мастера')
    portfolio = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name='Фотографии работ')
    salon = models.ManyToManyField(Salon, verbose_name='Салон мастера')
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Services, verbose_name='Услуги мастера')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Мастер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Мастера'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text='Формат ввода: +70123456789', verbose_name='Телефон')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Электронная почта')
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата и время записи')
    salon = models.ForeignKey(Salon, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выбор салона для записи')
    services = models.ForeignKey(Services, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выбор услуги')
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выбор мастера')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Клиент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Клиенты'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

serializers.py

```
from decouple import config
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from rest_framework import serializers

from salon.models import User


class UserRecordsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(UserRecordsSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['date'] = instance.date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y в %H:%M')
        return representation

    def create(self, validate_data):
        instance = super(UserRecordsSerializer, self).create(validate_data)
        send_mail(
            f'Приветствуем! Напоминаем о вашей записи на услугу: {instance.services} в нашем салоне красоты.',
            f'{instance.name}, ждем Вас {instance.date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y в %H:%M")} в салоне: {instance.salon}. Если у вас возникли изменения в планах или вам нужно перенести запись, пожалуйста, свяжитесь с нами по номеру: +70123456789. С нетерпением ждем встречи!',
            config('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
            [config('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL')],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        print('Новая запись на почте')
        return instance
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from salon.models import User
from salon.serializers import UserRecordsSerializer


class UserRecords(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRecordsSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'delete', 'head', 'options']
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```